I am trying to install nhost in my windows 11 from the documentation, the curl command doesn't seem to work
From the official documentation
I have Docker, Git, WSL2 already installed.
On running > sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nhost/cli/main/get.sh | bash
Error :
sudo : the term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nhost/cli/main/get.sh  ...
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sudo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I ran the command without sudo, and then the error is :
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'L'.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nhost/cli/main/get.sh | bas ...
+      ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

I thought of trying gsudo but it doesnt have Nhost as an application.

fyi this is off-topic here

Solution :
I installed Ubuntu version20 from Microsoft Store and then ran the command on the Ubuntu Terminal. It worked.
